# Improving plot execution time

Tags: plotting

Let me first show what I'm trying to do, and then I will ask the question.

I defined three function

```
BumpFunction[x_] := Exp[-x^2/(1-x^2)]

IntegrateBumpFunction[x_] := NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, x}]

IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized[x_] := NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, x}]/NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, 1}]
```

Then, I will use `Timing` to measure the time spend to plot the functions `IntegrateBumpFunction` and `IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized`.

```
Timing[Plot[IntegrateBumpFunction[x], {x,-1,1}]]
Timing[Plot[IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized[x], {x,-1,1}]]
```

You will see that there is a runtime difference. The cause of this discrepancy is in the denominator `NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, 1}]` in the function `IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized`. In my opinion this happen because the `Plot` function calls the `IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized` function several times during its execution and you always have to evaluate the integral `NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, 1}]`. This causes an increase in time to plot.bvd

My question is: Is it possible to avoid this problem by telling the plot function evaluate the term `NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t] , {t, 0, 1}]` only once?

Thanks.

Comment: Any function that uses a numeric technique (e.g., [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) should have its argument(s) restricted to numeric values ([`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)), e.g., `IntegrateBumpFunction[x_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` is preferable to `Timing` in modern multi-threaded CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change definition of normalized function

```
nor = NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t], {t, 0, 1}]; 
IntegrateBumpFunctionNormalized[x_] := 
    NIntegrate[BumpFunction[t], {t, 0, x}]/nor
```

Or, ultrafast, integrate with `NDSolve` , so you don't  have to integrate as many times as you have plotPoints, but only once generate an interpolating fucntion.

```
BumpFunction[x_] = Exp[-x^2/(1 - x^2)];

bfsol = bf /. 
  First@NDSolve[{bf'[x] == BumpFunction[x], bf[0] == 0}, 
bf, {x, -1, 1}]

Timing[Plot[bfsol[x], {x, -1, 1}]]
Timing[Plot[bfsol[x]/bfsol[1], {x, -1, 1}]]
```

Comment: Shorter, if plotting only: `NDSolveValue[{bf'[x] == BumpFunction[x], bf[0] == 0}, bf, {x, -1, 1}] // ListLinePlot`,
though normalized is not quite as slick:
`NDSolveValue[{bf'[x] == BumpFunction[x], bf[0] == 0},  {Indexed[bf@"Coordinates", 1], bf@"ValuesOnGrid"/bf[1]}, {x, -1, 1}] // Transpose // ListLinePlot` (+1)

Comment: Hi @Akku14. Your answer really works. However, I was trying to keep all the computation within a single function and not separate parts. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi @jonjones, _"trying to keep all the computation within a single function"_ is a new request, not something you specified in your original question. I think that moving the goalpost after receiving a good answer is not nice. Probably you can ask a new question with all the new requirements spelt out explicitly from the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelE2 , thanks for the tips from a real expert.

Comment: Hello @rhermans, . I think you are right. The answer was really good and I had no intention of belittling the answer gave by Michael E2.